# How come that, being submerged in his Bacta Tank, Vader can hear the voice of Vaneé from the outside?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In the film *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*, there is a scene at Darth Vader's castle on Mustafar where we can see Vader fully submerged in bacta fluid inside his rejuve tank. Then, after the announcing, from his attendant Vaneé, of Director Krennik's arrival, the tank began to empty and we can see part of Varder's head which does not appear to wear any hearing aid. I ask, is there a canon or legend explanation about how is possible that Vader can hear his attendant’s voice?

[image: Still of Rogue One: A Star Wars Story]

Comment: conversely, is there any reason to think he couldn't hear through the glass / bacta? Is there canon evidence that those materials are sound proof? Also...the Force? ;)

Comment: If you're floating quietly below the surface in a (calm, quiet) swimming pool it _is_ possible to hear people talking on the deck, as long as you're paying attention.  It's probably even quieter inside his tank, and there's a nice solid crystal-bacta fluid interface to transmit sound, as opposed to a mushy air-water interface.

Comment: Also: The Force